# Power BI Embedded can I also Embed the web power bi designer

Tags: powerbi-embedded

Customer can only see their data through this web application which is on azure ad domain. 
If I embed Power BI to the web application is it possible to embed the power bi web designer as well?

Just trying to find a way to use embedded without giving the user direct access to the cubes and db from their Power BI desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the report in View or in Edit modes. Probably the later one is what you are looking for. See [Embed Configuration Details](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details#options) for more details.

```
var embedConfig = {
  ...
  permissions: models.Permissions.All
  viewMode: models.ViewMode.Edit
```

You can also switch from view to edit mode and vise versa with following code:

```
report.switchMode("edit");
report.switchMode("view");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What happen if they want to design a new report? Do I embed a blank report in edit mode?

Comment: You can use [Clone Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/clonereportingroup) REST API call to copy the template (blank) and edit it, but why are you trying to re-invent Power BI Desktop?

Comment: The client have their own domain but all the data and cube  is in the application's Azure domain.  With Power BI Deskstop they can't connect  to the cube with their company's domain.  So if I use the web Power bi design on  and embed it to the application then the client can design power bi report on the web inside the Azure domain. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you trying to implement "app owns data" scenario? Here are the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers) and the [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples).